# Web scraping with Python Beautiful Soup - extracting single value

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I extract the values 'Hold' and '7' from the HTML code below?

```
<div class="row" data-key=hold>
  <div class="label">
     Hold
  </div>
  <div class="barContainer">
     <div class='bar ' style="width: 100.0%">
     </div>
     <div class="value" style="left: 100.0%">
        7
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: That's not the kind of question that is welcome on SO. First, _try_ doing things. Write some code. If the code does not work, come back again and ask a _specific_ question about your code.

Comment: @manjeetss, any issue if you try to get the values like this `find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='row']").text` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can can get an attribute value based on the tag and the attribute using `.find`, passing a dictionary as paramater, and then indexing the specific attribute, so:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''<div class="row" data-key=hold>
  <div class="label">
     Hold
  </div>
  <div class="barContainer">
     <div class='bar ' style="width: 100.0%">
     </div>
     <div class="value" style="left: 100.0%">
        7
     </div>
  </div>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
```

And then:

```
>>> soup.find('div', {'class':"row"})['data-key']
'hold'

>>> soup.find('div', {'class':"value"}).text  # or .contents to get a list
'\n        7\n     '
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, but unfortunately I am getting the following error messages: For "Hold" value: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "IGIndexDataScrape_Daily_v0.4.py", line 51, in <module>
    print soup.find('div', {'class':"row"})['data-key'].text
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'.       For "7" value error message:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "IGIndexDataScrape_Daily_v0.4.py", line 51, in <module>
    print soup.find('div', {'class':"value"}).text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Are you defining soup befotehand, I'll edit my answer to make it more complete.

Comment: I have tried the below, but it's also not working:  print soup.find('h1', class_='secondary-header').find('span', class_='marketNameHeader').text.  Error message:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "IGIndexDataScrape_Daily_v0.4.py", line 39, in <module>
    print soup.find('div', class_='row').find('div', class_='label').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: @manjeetss Please check my edit, it should work if done all steps.

Comment: print soup.select('div.row div.label')[0].text   gives me a list index out of bounds error.  Not sure what to do?

Comment: @manjeetss just don't use `select`, use the function I mention in my answer.

Comment: I am still getting the following error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    soup.find('div', {'class':"row"})['data-key']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'.  I am really not sure where I am going wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Full code: import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.ig.com/uk/marketanalysis/ig-shares/network-healthcare-holdings-ltd-NTC-ZA'


page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
soup.find('div', {'class':"row"})['data-key']
soup.find('div', {'class':"value"}).text

Comment: @manjeetss Well, that page doesn't have any part of the html code you provided in the question, so it won't work!

Comment: Thanks very much Vinicius. I tried the code and realised that unless you are logged in to the website, you are not going to see the code I copied and pasted; the webpage content is more detailed once logged in. When I tried to extract other data from the non-logged in page i.e. the page you can see if you are not logged in then I don't get the same error message. Thanks very much again for your help. I guess my question has been resolved.

Comment: @manjeetss I'm glad to help! If my answer/comments were helpful, would you upvote the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen('http://whateverdomain.com')
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
requiredContainer = bsObj.find("div", {'class':'row'})

holdValue = requiredContainer.find("div", {'class':'label'}).text
print(holdValue)

sevenValue = requiredContainer.find('div', {'class':'value'}).text
print(sevenValue)
```

Replace `whateverdomain.com` with the webpage from which you are scraping.

I used the below html page to test.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row" data-key=hold>
      <div class="label">
         Hold
      </div>
      <div class="barContainer">
         <div class='bar ' style="width: 100.0%">
         </div>
         <div class="value" style="left: 100.0%">
            7
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

To run locally save the html page and load it using, `html = urlopen('file:///path/to/index.html')`

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, but unfortunately I am getting the error message:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "IGIndexDataScrape_Daily_v0.4.py", line 52, in <module>
    holdValue = requiredContainer.find('div', {'class':'label'}).text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: @manjeetss, It running fine on my system. I have added the html page i used to test to my code. Try saving the html page locally and try running the  python script

Comment: Thanks very much diabolicfreak. I tried the code and realised that unless you are logged in to the website, you are not going to see the code I copied and pasted; the webpage content is more detailed once logged in. When I tried to extract other data from the non-logged in page i.e. the page you can see if you are not logged in then I don't get the same error message. Thanks very much again for your help. I guess my question has been resolved.